# Square of largest area inscribed in a right triangle

Tags: geometry

I was solving a question while I was stuck at a point. The question wanted me to find the length of the side of the square of largest possible area that can be inscribed in a given right triangle.
But I was thinking whether how to prove that the square with largest area is the one whose two of the sides coincide with the legs of the right triangle.
I've tried proving that but I couldn't figure any way out. 
Can someone help me prove it in an easy way?

The answer that is being linked to it as duplicate does not give specific proof for a right triangle.

Comment: It's not duplicate....

Comment: If you read the accepted answer to that question, you'll also find the answer to your question.